# Windows 7 does not "see" Arduino Uno R3 board in its Device Manager

Tags: windows, arduino

I'm not sure if this is a proper place to ask such question, but I'm ran of ideas. I have plugged Arduino Uno R3 board to my laptop via USB and I try to install Arduino's drivers, but to do so, I have to have it visible on my `Device Manager`. And here is a problem, because I do not see anything which can be my Arduino board. I do not have even a `Other Devices` category in it, or a node `Unknown Device`. In addition, Arduino's the ON led is not lit. I have Windows 7 Home Edition.

Comment: Instead of editing your answer into the question, please move your solution down into the answers section and accept it instead.

Comment: But... you answered your own question after 15 minutes? Anyway.. Why did you install the FTDI drivers, since Arduino UNO R3 uses an Atmel chip? They also state `Finally, navigate to and select the driver file named "arduino.inf", located in the "Drivers" folder of the Arduino Software download (not the "FTDI USB Drivers" sub-directory).` see [the arduino guide page](http://arduino.cc/en/guide/windows#toc4)

Comment: Read carefully what I've wrote. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem:

1. Push `Start` menu button and type in the searchbox `hdwwiz`. Click on `hdwwiz.exe` and wizard will open.
2. Choose `Install hardware I select from a list`.
3. In the list below select `Ports (COM & LPT)`.
4. In the next screen you should be able to select `Arduino` in the left box.
5. In the right box you should be able to select your type of `Arduino`.
6. You can click `Next` in order to try install drivers automatically, or you can click the `Have Disk` and point to the `FTDI USB` drivers located in e.g. `C:\Arduino\drivers\FTDI USB Drivers` depending where you installed the `Arduino 1.X.X` package (http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software#toc2)
7. After installation is complete in your `Device Manager` you should now see `Ports (COM & LPT)` node and subnode in it called e.g. `Arduino Uno (COM3)`.
8. Right click on it and go through the instructions described in section `4 Install the drivers` described at http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows.

PS **Before you try solution described above**, uninstall your Arduino software, unplug your board, and be sure to **FIRST** plug the board to your computer and **NEXT** install the Arduino's software. In some cases it also may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problem, you can fix it from device manager. The solution was to select "Let me pick from a a list of device drivers on my computer" once you right click and try to update driver. I got this solution from here:
http://eestuffs.com/2017/01/19/fix-arduino-driver-install-problem/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, the IDE was not showing port selection or detecting my board.
So, I just installed dpinst-amd64.exe from drivers folders under arduino setup folder.
{your path}:\arduino-1.8.3-windows\arduino-1.8.3\drivers
and install dpinst-amd64.exe

It works fine for me on windows